# Comparing one column values with spaces in between with another one in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: string, oracle, compare

I need to compare one column values to another column values in the below table "BRAND". I tried considering the length of the string alone between two columns but in spite of that.. the values in the columns differ and so it is giving incorrect result.

Table BRAND:

```
ID       brand_1             brand_2        Status
---------------------------------------------------   
1        SAC                 SAC            True
2        APP BBB             BBB APP        True
3        ABC OND DEG         DEG ABC OND    True
4        GIF                 APP GIF        False
5        GHY PPA             GHY PPA ABC    False
6        MNC CGA IPK         GIT ABC ITY    False
```

I need to return the rows that are False since there is no matching between the columns brand_1 and brand_2. The Status column doesn't exist in the data; I added it here to demonstrate which rows are considered "false" and should be returned. This column shouldn't exist in the output either.

**Output:**

```
 ID        brand_1             brand_2     
------------------------------------------- 
4          GIF                 APP GIF       
5          GHY PPA             GHY PPA ABC   
6          MNC CGA IPK         GIT ABC ITY
```

Please help me out.

Comment: What are: (1) the Oracle version (as in, 11.2.0.4 or 12.2.0.1 - find out with `select * from v$version`; (2) your expected level of knowledge? Can you use user-defined types, nested tables, the `lateral` clause, etc.? Then: ID = 4, under brand_2, has TWO spaces in the middle; is that a mistake? Or do two spaces count as a `null` between them? In other words: are `AAA BBB` and `BBB   AAA` considered the same, even though they have a different number of spaces in the middle?

Comment: Hi Mathguy, for ID =4 , there should be only One space and not Two. By mistake, it came up as two spaces.  And yes, AAA BBB and BBB AAA are considered same.

Comment: Oracle version : 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: Hi Mathguy, i'm executing the same and able to see the result.Thank you so much. I'm doing some more testing with the data. In case, if I want just the Output as below without "Status" to be displayed and return whatever is false.Please tell me how to do that.                                       
ID         brand_1            brand_2  
--------------------------------------------------- 
4        GIF                       APP  GIF      
5        GHY PPA             GHY PPA ABC    
6        MNC CGA IPK     GIT ABC ITY

Comment: Sorry,I'm not able to give proper format for table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way (not the fastest, but easy to write and maintain). The idea is to split each input string into its components, sort them alphabetically and then reassemble them. I do that using `lateral` (so each row is processed independently of other rows), a `JSON` trick to split the strings, and `LISTAGG` to put them back together.

```
with
  brand (id, brand_1, brand_2) as (
    select 1, 'SAC'        , 'SAC'         from dual union all
    select 2, 'APP BBB'    , 'BBB APP'     from dual union all
    select 3, 'ABC OND DEG', 'DEG ABC OND' from dual union all
    select 4, 'GIF'        , 'APP GIF'     from dual union all
    select 5, 'GHY PPA'    , 'GHY PPA ABC' from dual union all
    select 6, 'MNC CGA IPK', 'GIT ABC ITY' from dual
  )
select id, brand_1, brand_2,
       case when b1 = b2 then 'True' else 'False' end as status
from   brand,
       lateral( select listagg(token, ' ') within group (order by token) as b1
                from json_table( '["' || replace(brand_1, ' ','","') || '"]',
                                 '$[*]'  columns(token varchar2 path '$'))
              ),
       lateral( select listagg(token, ' ') within group (order by token) as b2
                from json_table( '["' || replace(brand_2, ' ','","') || '"]',
                                 '$[*]'  columns(token varchar2 path '$'))
              )
;

ID BRAND_1     BRAND_2     STATUS
-- ----------- ----------- ------
 1 SAC         SAC         True 
 2 APP BBB     BBB APP     True 
 3 ABC OND DEG DEG ABC OND True 
 4 GIF         APP GIF     False
 5 GHY PPA     GHY PPA ABC False
 6 MNC CGA IPK GIT ABC ITY False
```

**Edit**: To get the desired result in the **edited** question, remove the `case` expression from the `SELECT` clause, and add a `WHERE` clause at the end of the query: `... where b1 != b2` (assuming the input strings can't be null; if they can be null, you will have to handle according to your business needs).

Comment: Hi Mathguy, the **Output** has to return just False status records as below. I also does not  need **Status** column to be displayed: Please let me know how to do that. I appreciate your help.                                                                                  **ID**         **brand_1**     **brand_2**     
--------------------------------------------------- 
4        GIF                      APP  GIF       
5        GHY PPA             GHY PPA ABC     
6        MNC CGA IPK         GIT ABC ITY

Comment: @Anitha - I hope you were able to answer your own questions - they are both very basic. If you want to keep only the rows where `b1 != b2`, then add a `where` clause at the very end of the query (`where b1 != b2`); and if you don't want the `STATUS` column, remove the corresponding code (the `case` expression) from the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Yes I'm able to do that. No worries! Thank you!